# Filter Django objects by .extra() select for lat and lng radius

Tags: django, django-models

I has a Django models for location based services and try to filter location by radius.

I try use `.extra()` query but not working. The value of distance can only use for sort, not filter.

```
# models.py
class Location(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "shop_location"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.place_name

# views.py
shop_locations = Location.objects.extra(
        select={
            'distance': '6371 * acos( cos( radians(9) )'
            '* cos( radians( COALESCE(latitude, 0) ) )'
            '* cos( radians( COALESCE(longitude, 0) )'
            '- radians(11) ) + sin( radians(9) )'
            '* sin( radians( COALESCE(latitude, 0) ) ) )'
        },
    ).extra(order_by=['distance']).filter(distance<10) # on radius 10KM
```

But return error `name 'distance' is not defined`.
How to fix it. 
I don't want use GeoDjango.

Comment: You should use `distance__lt=10`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, not working. Still error